# Nest JS .env file variables are undefined even though im using ConfigModule

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, nestjs

My variables are undefined but im using .env file in the root of the project that same way it is described in the documentation. Also adding condif imported from 'dotenv' works.

```js
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config();
```

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { PodcastsModule } from './podcasts/podcasts.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config();
const { HOST, PORT, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE } = process.env;
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    PodcastsModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: HOST,
      port: parseInt(PORT),
      username: USER,
      password: PASSWORD,
      database: DATABASE,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time you are destructuring `process.env`, `dotenv.config()` has not yet been ran and the `process.env` has not beed populated. You can either call `dotenv.config()` as **the very first thing** in your `main.ts` file, or you can use [asynchronous registration](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#async-configuration) and use the `ConfigService` inside of `TypeormModule.forRootASync()` like so:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    PodcastsModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres', // you may need to add an `as const` here
        host: config.get('HOST'),
        port: parseInt(config.get('PORT')),
        username: config.get('USER'),
        password: config.get('PASSWORD'),
        database: config.get('DATABASE'),
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        synchronize: true,
      })
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```